# Custom non-bubbling events and jQuery delegated handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am developing an application for Tizen using jQuery. Tizen's mouse events leave much to be desired, so I am unfortunately forced to create my own events which fix the shortcomings of the platform. (I have contacted Samsung about this and they hinted that they may fix these issues in a future release)

For this reason I have implemented my events something like this:

```
$currentlyHovered.trigger("tizenmouseout");

for(var i = oldStack.length - 1; i > matching; i--) {
    $(oldStack[i]).triggerHandler("tizenmouseleave");
}

$newlyHovered.trigger("tizenmouseover");


for(var i = newStack.length - 1; i > matching; i--) {
    $(newStack[i]).triggerHandler("tizenmouseenter");
}
```

I've got my tizenmouseover/tizenmouseout events working perfectly. My tizenmouseenter and tizenmouseleave events mostly work, but they have issues when interacting with jQuery live/delegated handlers.

I believe the reason for this is that, true to [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter), my tizenmouseenter/tizenmouseleave events do not bubble. jQuery briefly mentions this in [their documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, a few events such as change and submit do not natively bubble but jQuery patches these to bubble and create consistent cross-browser behavior.

They imply that events that do not bubble are nonstandard and only a feature of outdated browsers, when in reality the mouseenter/mouseleave events do not bubble and are supported in every major modern browser. They do mention though that they manually patch these non-bubbling events, which explains why the browser's native mouseenter and mouseleave events work.

Anyway, delegated handlers are not triggered when I call my custom tizenmouseenter or tizenmouseleave events. I am not able to change my custom events to bubble as this would largely defeat the purpose of them.

Is there a way I can somehow tap into jQuery's event bubbling patch so that my custom events have the same behaviour?

Comment: if you don't bubble you can't delegate. i don't see the harm in bubbling anyway...

Comment: The native mouseenter and mouseleave events work just fine with delegated events.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Proof that the native events work: http://codepen.io/YM_Industries/pen/BKdaOg

Comment: @dandavis The point of mouseleave is that it only fires when the mouse has entirely left the element, and not simply moved into one of the element's children. Basically, mouseleave fires when :hover is deactivated on the element. If mouseleave bubbled, it would also fire when the mouse left any of the element's descendants, which completely defeats the purpose of the event. Similar issues occur if mouseenter bubbles too.

Comment: you can tell what elm triggered the event via `e.target`, and you can use `elm.contains()` to check for descendants. ex for this page in console: `document.body.contains(tabcomplete)`. i realize the simplicity of enter/leave, i'm just trying to find something workable for you...

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the workaround suggestion. I may have to do that unfortunately, but I'm hoping someone has a nicer way of achieving the results I want.

Comment: you may have better luck using CSS's hover. if the env supports `transitionend` events, a 1ms transition on hover defined in CSS _might_ hit like a sniper

Comment: My custom events also add/remove a class called "tizenhovered" to hovered elements, which I use for styling. I'm trying to keep the solution fairly generic so I don't believe adding a transition to every element that needs these events will work, but I appreciate the creativity of the idea.